# ABCPdf unable to find type or namespace PDFTable

Tags: .net, asp.net-core-3.1, abcpdf

I am using ABCPdf to insert Table of contents on the first page in my **.NET Core 3.1** project. Compiler is unable to find `PDFTable` class as mentioned [here](https://www.websupergoo.com/helppdfnet/default.htm?page=source%2f4-examples%2f09-table1.htm) in documentation.

Sample code below:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using WebSupergoo.ABCpdf12;

namespace AddTableOfContents
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            Doc doc = new Doc();
            doc.FontSize = 96;
            doc.AddText("Hello World");
            doc.Save("simple.pdf");
            PDFTable theTable = new PDFTable(doc, 5); //error here

        }
}
```

> Error: The type or namespace PDFTable could not be found